# Why does Joomla remove html tags from submitted text even when filter types are set to raw?

Tags: jform, filter

I'm trying to retrieve and save a html formatted text submitted thru a Joomla editor field. I went thru some of the available docs (https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput#Getting_Multiple_Values), but unfortunately I could not figure out why Joomla removes all the HMTL tags from the text agains all my efforts. I already set the filter type of the field to "raw":

```
<field
    name="Message"
    type="editor"
    label="Message"
    rows="10"
    cols="40" 
    filter="raw"
    class="gngcontact"
/>
```

I'm trying to use the below code to retrieve the field content after submission:

```
$input = new JInput;
$post = $input->getArray(array($_POST => 'RAW'));
GNGHelper::dump($post);
```

But this still results in a string without HMTL:

string(62) "Hello!
Are there any tags in this line? There were some..."

What else do I need to do to be able to keep the tags in the resulting string?

Thanks a bunch!
W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$_POST` as array key in `getArray()` argument is producing a warning:

> Warning: Illegal offset type

If your form is using form control (normally `jform`), you can get unfiltered data like this:

```
$post = $this->input->get('jform', array(), 'raw');
```